# IIS 7.0 on a Windows Server 20102 R2 does not display a web page in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis, html

The root website /  application directory displays the landing .aspx page correctly. one of the links points to a page in subfolder. Clicking this link generates a CONNECTION_REFUSED error. What can I do please?

Comment: what is the extension of the page in the subfolder?  IE .aspx, .html

Comment: The extension is .aspx

Comment: That looks like a database error.  Is the page doing something?  Are you getting a yellow screen of death?

Comment: no, in IE receive : This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://localhost is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Fix connection problems - in Chrome: "This webpage is not available

Reload Hide details - at the end: Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - it could be a database connection error. Let me install VS express to test DB connection via SSMS.

Comment: I just tested DB connection successfully. DB connection issues are ruled out?

Comment: Have you checked the security settings on the folders in the site?

Comment: Log file content: 2014-12-09 20:25:39 ::1 GET /sf/my_safe/login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 906  then nothing else. On another DEV server, there are many more entries which indicate activity of fetching page contents.

Comment: I may have to apply a Self-Signed SSL certificate on the IIS server. I will try it out and post later.